# How to parse log lines using Spark that could span multiple lines

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, multiline

I'm developing a Spark/Scala Application that can read and parse a custom log file. I'm having trouble parsing multi-line log entries. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
case class MLog(dateTime: String, classification: String, serverType: String, identification:String, operation: String)
val PATTERN = """(?s)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\s+(\w+)s+\[(.*)\]\s+\[(.*)\]\s+(.*)"""


def parseLogLine(log: String): MLog={
     val res = PATTERN.findFirstMatchIn(log)
     if (res.isEmpty) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Cannot parse log line: " + log)

     MLog(m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3),m.group(4),m.group(5))
}

sc.textFile("/mydirectory/logfile").map(parseLogLine).foreach(println)
```

Some of the entries in logfile span multiple lines. The regex works fine for single line entries but when a multi-line entry is read like the one shown below,

```
2015-08-31 00:10:17,682 WARN  [ScheduledTask-10] [name=custname;mid=9999;ds=anyvalue;] datasource - Scheduled DataSource import failed.                 
com.xxx.common.service.ServiceException: system failure: Unable to connect to ANY server: LdapDataSource{id=xxx, type=xxx, enabled=true, name=xxx, host=xxx port=999, connectionType=ssl, username=xxx, folderId=99999}
```

I receive this error:

> Cannot parse log line:com.xxx.common.service.ServiceException: system failure: Unable to connect to ANY server: LdapDataSource{id=xxx, type=xxx, enabled=true, name=xxx, host=xxx port=999, connectionType=ssl, username=xxx, folderId=99999}

How can I get Spark to read multi-line log entries from a log file?

Comment: How big are individual files? Can these fit on a single worker?

Comment: Yes. The file is small -  about 40MB. The function, will print out the single line entries but when it reaches a multi-line entry, it fails with the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since input files are small you can use `SparkContext.wholeTextFiles`.

```
// Parse a single file and return all extracted entries
def parseLogFile(log: String): Iterator[MLog] = {
    val p: scala.util.matching.Regex = ???
    p.findAllMatchIn(log).map(
        m => MLog(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(5))
    )
}

val rdd: RDD[MLog] = sc
   .wholeTextFiles("/path/to/input/dir")
   .flatMap{case (_, txt) => parseLogFile(txt)}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! What if I wanted to use the sc.textFiles method? The log files could  grow very large over time and I want to make sure I can still use the same code.

Comment: There is no single method to process multiline records in general. If you can handle some information loss you can simply `mapPartitions` and drop incomplete records. If not you can write a custom Hadoop input format or `mapPartitions` and fix records spanning over two partitions later. Finally you can try configure your logging to keep input files at the reasonable size that can be handled by a single worker.

Comment: how to determine if a file is small enough to be handled by wholeTextFiles()? (my files are ~250 MB ...)

Comment: @c-rod Here is an example using textFile where the main difference is using the Regex method `findFirstMatchIn` which returns Option[Match] instead of `findAllMatchIn` which returns Iterator[Match] and using `map` instead of `flatmap`. In the `wholeTextFiles` example, you want an iterator because it will contain all the Matches in the file, hence the need to flatmap that Iterator. With textFile, you just `map` rows. see: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/34362/parsing-apache-log-files-with-spark.html Note that textFile method will split rows so no multi-line. You need wholeTextFiles